# Matrix Multiplication Application

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix representing the amount of different resources (columns) I would need to create (rows) different objects.

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

My objective is to use matrix multiplication to find out how many resources it would take if we wanted to have i objects of row 1, j objects of row 2, and k objects of row 3.

I don't know an efficient way to go about this. A working solution  I have is to split each of the rows and multiply them by scalars i, j, k, but I don't feel as though this is the correct solution.

Is there a way to get the same result by multiplying two matrices? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described *is* matrix multiplication, and is the correct way to solve the problem.

Let $M$ stand for the $3 \times 5$ resource matrix in the question. Then the
$1 \times 5$ matrix
$$
[i,j,k]M
$$
tells you how many of each of the five kinds of resources you need to manufacture those objects.

The matrix product would look a little more traditional if you wrote the transpose $T$ of the resource consumption matrix instead, where each row corresponds to an ingredient and each column to a kind of object. Then the computation would be the $1 \times 5$ matrix
$$
T
\begin{bmatrix}
i \\ j \\ k
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain the [i,j,k]A notation?

Comment: Multiply the $1\times 3$ matrix $[i,j,k]$ bythe $3 \times 5$ matrix $A$.